# SQL SERVER/PHP Differences In Returning Values

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) as Sequence,
varchar(100), REPLACE(RIGHT('000000000000000'+CAST(value AS VARCHAR(15)),15), '.', '') as GroupValue

FROM TABLE...
```

In SQL Management Studio, the values return as expected:

```
Sequence: 1
GroupValue: 00000000000100
```

But in PHP (XAMPP 1.7.4, PHP: 5.3.5), when I try to retrieve the values, thay are empty ("", not NULL). They are the only values in the query that are giving me this error, all others are normal.

Any clues?

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anybody to have much chance in helping. Why did you bother with a distinct here? You can't get more than 1 row since you have top 1.

Comment: Indeed is a unecessary piece of query. How can I make this question better? What info do you need?

Comment: At the very least an actual query would be a good place to start. This has the appearance of being part of a larger query. Not sure what you mean by retrieving the values are empty string. You then state you know what they are. Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Also include the php code where you query and get the unexpected result. What is `varchar(100)` doing in your query?